# Capturing epoch count when using EarlyStopping feature with Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, callback

I working my way through using Keras Modeling and think I have now sussed how to use the callback feature to trap the best fit and prevent overfitting; all seems good. Whilst I can understand the verbose parameter will display the information I require it makes the output messy and I prefer to set this to zero. I would though still like to somehow capture the "epoch" count that gave the best result to incorporate into my own display; is there some way I can get at this?  Thanks

```
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse' )] 
    cbfile = 'best_model.h5'
    calls = [
    EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='auto', verbose=0, patience=10),\
    ModelCheckpoint(cbfile, monitor = 'val_loss', mode = 'auto',\
            save_best_only = True ) ]
    history = model.fit(Xvect, Yvect, epochs=mcycl, batch_size=32,\
            validation_split=dsplit, verbose=0, callbacks = calls )
    saved = load_model('best_model.h5')        
    score = saved.evaluate(Xvect, Yvect, verbose=0)
    print('"Overall loss for best fit":',np.round(score,4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about writing your own custom `EarlyStopping` callback? The [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback#early_stopping_at_minimum_loss) docs provide a very good example of how you could get started:

```py
import numpy as np


class EarlyStoppingAtMinLoss(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    """Stop training when the loss is at its min, i.e. the loss stops decreasing.

  Arguments:
      patience: Number of epochs to wait after min has been hit. After this
      number of no improvement, training stops.
  """

    def __init__(self, patience=0):
        super(EarlyStoppingAtMinLoss, self).__init__()
        self.patience = patience
        # best_weights to store the weights at which the minimum loss occurs.
        self.best_weights = None

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        # The number of epoch it has waited when loss is no longer minimum.
        self.wait = 0
        # The epoch the training stops at.
        self.stopped_epoch = 0
        # Initialize the best as infinity.
        self.best = np.Inf

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current = logs.get("loss")
        if np.less(current, self.best):
            self.best = current
            self.wait = 0
            # Record the best weights if current results is better (less).
            self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
        else:
            self.wait += 1
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True
                print("Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.")
                self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)

    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        if self.stopped_epoch > 0:
            print("Epoch %05d: early stopping" % (self.stopped_epoch + 1))
```

Note the `self.stopped_epoch` variable in the example. This way you have full control of what you display and how your early stopping logic works. Furthermore, using the `logs` dictionary, you can access your current loss and accuracy for epoch x. On the other hand, if you just want to use a simple print statement after training your model, you could just get the last epoch of your callback and print it:

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse' )] 
cbfile = 'best_model.h5'
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='auto', verbose=0, patience=10)

calls = [early_stopping,
ModelCheckpoint(cbfile, monitor = 'val_loss', mode = 'auto',\
            save_best_only = True ) ]
history = model.fit(Xvect, Yvect, epochs=mcycl, batch_size=32,\
            validation_split=dsplit, verbose=0, callbacks = calls )
saved = load_model('best_model.h5')        
score = saved.evaluate(Xvect, Yvect, verbose=0)

print('"Overall loss for best fit":',np.round(score,4)) 
print("Epoch %05d: early stopping" % (early_stopping.stopped_epoch + 1))
```

Comment: Much appreciated tried and seems to work fine; the issue I am having at the moment is knowing that ".stopped_epoch" was even an attribute of a "EarlyStopping" object. I can search and find parameters for EarlyStopping but how do I find listings and documentation for the attributes, I just seem to draw a blank when I search?

Comment: I usually go and check it out the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.6.0/keras/callbacks.py#L1693-L1833) directly. Since the docs, do often leave out the attributes.